# django response download png and tiff files

Tags: python, django

So I have this code that downloads images which are either PNG or TIFF:

```
image = Image.open(design.design.path)
format = image.format
extension = str(format)
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='image/' + extension.lower())
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % file_name
image.save(response, format)

return response
```

This code works perfectly with PNG files however when I try to download TIFF file I get the following error:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/marijus/workspace/virtualenvs/casta/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/marijus/workspace/virtualenvs/casta/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/marijus/workspace/casta/designs/views.py" in index
  103.             image.save(response, format, quality=95, optimize=True)
File "/Users/marijus/workspace/virtualenvs/casta/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py" in save
  1682.             save_handler(self, fp, filename)
File "/Users/marijus/workspace/virtualenvs/casta/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py" in _save
  1173.                     atts[k] = bytes(v.encode('ascii', 'replace')) + b"\0"

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 42: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like this is a file name error not really related to the file format. What happens if you rename said file?

You can also run the file name through an encoder and ignore all non-utf8 characters. For example:

```
>>> u'aあä'.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
'a'
```